# Update sqlite not working on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a login and reset password activity. When I enter the new updated password and try to login again, I cannot do so with the new password. Logging in with the old password works fine. Basically, the password field is not getting updated/overwritten.

There is no error in the logcat. Just that the password is not updated.

Please help as I am new to android development.

Code for update( DataRegister is the class with GET AND SET functions):

```
public int updatePassword(DataRegister dataregister) {

db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues updated = new ContentValues();
updated.put("PASSWORD", dataregister.getPASSWORD());

return db.update(DataRegister.TABLE, updated, "EMAIL=?" , new String[]   {dataregister.getEMAIL()});

}
```

Code for retrieval:

```
public String getPass(DataRegister dataRegister) {

db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(DataRegister.TABLE, null, "EMAIL=?",
        new String[]{dataRegister.getEMAIL()}, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())

{
    pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
}
return pass;


// return contact


}
```

Code for Login:

```
  String email = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        dataRegister.setEMAIL(email);

        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        dataRegister.setPASSWORD(password);

        String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(dataRegister);

        Toast.makeText(Login.this, storedPassword,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Boolean a=loginDataBaseAdapter.isExist(dataRegister.getEMAIL());
       validation = getSharedPreferences("myShaPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {

            Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                    "Congrats: Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        else {

                Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                        "User Name or Password does not match",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }



    }
});
```

Code for reset password:

```
public class ResetPassword extends AppCompatActivity {


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);

 email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.em2);
 dataRegister=new DataRegister();

loginDataBaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();



pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text12);
conpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text13);

email1 = email.getText().toString();
dataRegister.setEMAIL(email1);
pass1 = pass.getText().toString();

conpass1 = conpass.getText().toString();
dataRegister.setPASSWORD(conpass1);

Button btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {


        if (pass1.equals(conpass1)) {

         loginDataBaseAdapter.updatePassword(email1,pass1);
            String newpass =loginDataBaseAdapter.getPass(dataRegister);
```

Comment: is the password inside the database not updated or are you not able to get the updated password?

Comment: I tried to log in with the new password and i couldn't but i could log in with my old password. So i think that password doesn't update in the database. Do I have to call the onUpgrade function (from database helper) for it to update?

Comment: I put a Toast to check the password retrieval but it always shows a blank toast.

Comment: no, onUpgrade is only if your database structure is changing.

Comment: so we need to see the `getSingleEntry()` method....

Comment: Why can't i log in with my new password though? It works only when i enter my old password on the login page!

Comment: please post getSingleEntry() method.....

Comment: and what you are doing here in `ResetPassword()` method : 
`loginDataBaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();` ? why you are initializing the `loginDataBaseAdapter` twice in different ways?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough reputation for comment so I will write my suggestion as answer...sorry for that

I think it will help for u

In your getPass method

```
if (cursor != null)
cursor.moveToFirst()
    pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
```